# Alpha numeric string to corresponding key strokes

Tags: java

I was working on a problem where I need to convert a given alpha-numeric `String` to text based format (don't know what exactly to call it). `Example: a = 2, c = 222, f = 333` etc. To make it more clear, this is found on your phone's keypad. Like the way you text in the old hard key phones which didn't have QWERTY keyboard.

`Example: (INPUT) hello 
(OUTPUT) 44+33+555+555+666`

Here is what I had in mind. I can pre-load all the cases (26 + 10 over all) into a `HashMap` and use that. But I think there should be some other better way to do this right? All/any brilliant ideas are welcome.

Comment: What exactly does "text based format" mean?  Any examples of a conversion problem should always show input/output pairs.

Comment: if the conversions follow a formula you can just compute the formula ad-hoc. If not then I think the `Map` would work well.

Comment: @mellamokb: There you go, I have edited it to show a sample `input` and `output`

Comment: What is the output for a number, say `2`?  Should it be `2222`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashMap` would be the simplest way to do what you want

Because you are working with a static set of mappings, you might want to consider implementing your lookup table as a new class. I am thinking the internals of the class can just be an array of strings. When you do a lookup in the array, you can subtract the 'a' char from the character you are looking up and that will become the array index. (for the punctuation characters, if the result of the subtraction is not between 0 and 25, you can handle them with special cases). This method will bypass the hash function and improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to relate Strings (or maybe you ment single Characters!?) to numbers, there is no way easier than using some java.util.Map implementation.

For the computation part, you could first compute how often each Character in the String occurs and then add occurance(c) x numberFor(c) (2 x 555 instead of adding two times 555 in your example).

---

Update: come to think of it, for special cases, there might be optimizations. E.g. in the extreme case of mapping all to 0, the computation becomes trivial and no hashmap is required ;) Or maybe are all numbers positive? Maybe each alpha-numeric character maps to a different prime number?